# Writing Japanese chars into XML gives Junk value in java standalone program, but from eclipse gets proper output

Tags: java, jar

My problem is I have written a code in java to read some japanese chars and write into XML file. The program works fine when i am using eclipse with JRE 1.5 and 1.6 but when i created a *.jar file and run the same program standalone, the output i am getting some junk chracters. Can anybody please help me out? Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to run it with -Dfile.encoding=UTF8